# localhost:8000 is not working in loading laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on laravel project. First I encountered a fatal error of maximum number of bytes. I fixed that, after fixing and restarting my Apache when I started to run php artisan it worked correctly but now I'm not able to access my project in browser (after running) `php artisan`.
The browser just says page not found and the buffering of that page is like infinite. what's happening don't know !!! :(

Comment: any error messages in Apache error.log?

Comment: try to run composer dump-autoload and php artisan config:cache

Comment: sounds like a dodgy loop

Comment: Are you sure your Apache is listening on port 8000 and not the default 80

Comment: Clear cache and run your project + Check error logs!

Comment: no error message in Apache,when i type in: 'localhost:8000' the browser just start to load and then it goes for long time without loading the project.

Comment: BTW how to check Apache error.log?

Comment: "_(after running) php artisan_" `php artisan` ... and what? `php artisan` alone just prints all available artisan commands.

Comment: I mean after running server by running 'php artisan serve', the server started perfectly and then in the browser when I type 'localhost:8000' for my project files that just goes round and round,without showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change port using `--port` param,

```
php artisan serve --port=8000
```

Comment: still facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this command and use 8080 port number:
php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8080

Answer (score 0):

I changed the port and refreshed the server. It worked.

Initially:

```
app.listen(3000);
```

Later:

```
app.listen(3001);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not try running Laravel on a virtual host?